# Crystal Reports Crosstab Summary Row Count of Subset of Data

Tags: crystal-reports, crosstab

I have a crosstab report that counts the instances of records (that I have previously filtered via the Section Formula Record method).

I would now like to also include a second count of the records that are a subset of the original set of records.

IE In my booking app, I have a count of all the booked seats in a restaurant, I would now like a count of all the seats that were booked online.  (and of course this is all grouped by restaurant at the top and then each row is the day.

I hope that makes sense, - thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a formula such as IF <Booked_Online> Then 1 ELSE 0

Then, SUM that formula to get the count of booked online.